# HTTPS and SSL certificate

Tags: symfony, ssl, https

I develop a website with Symfony2 and I put it in HTTPS.

I have several questions:

1. The only way to don't have an error message on my browser when I go to my website is to have an SSL certificate?
2. How the installation of the SSL certificate on a website works?
3. Verisign offers SSL certificates from 450€/year ( http://www.symantec.com/fr/fr/page.jsp?id=compare-ssl-certificates ). It's quite expensive. Is there other good solutions to have a cheaper certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates tell the client you can be trusted. Web browsers come loaded with trusted keys from third parties. Your browser checks the key of the cert coming in and if it is in the list it allows SSL connection (if the IP address in the cert etc is correct). This is why it costs as no doubt the cert providers have their own expenses to be added to browsers and to turn a profit etc.

You can of course produce you own certificate but they won't be recognised by your clients machine. The user then has to explicitly accept the cert - some browsers like chrome make this hard as it is a security risk.

Google should help you find the best cert deals from trusted providers. 
Your hosting provider should be able to help you set up your cert. If your self hosting that should be its own question as it could have different answers depending on your set up.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Providers provide different certificates with different encryption strengths (it depends on the algorithm). Does it mean that it is the certificate which encrypts the communication between the server and the clients? Without certificate there is no secured HTTP communication?

Comment: The cert is descriptive. It is telling your browser that the server can be trusted. I presume the encryption strength is also telling the browser the expected encryption algorithm to use otherwise how will the browser know the correct one. The browser does the work.

Answer (score 2):

If your site is not shop or something commercial, you can get free cert at startssl.com

[See awesome tutorail](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps) 
(Installing certificate in nginx is almost the same with apache)

**UPD**

Now use letsencrypt :)